# Area learning and Marker Detection

Tags: google-project-tango, drift

Does area learning and marker detection work simultaneously? If we use marker detection to identify marker such as QR and place game object at it. Will enabling area learning minimize drift?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it appears that they both work together.  I have a project which localises to an ADF, and will also detect markers OK even after losing tracking and re-localising.